# Dashboard uneditable for System Administrator

Tags: dashboard, configuration

I have a dashboard which I can't edit though I am system administrator. There are other dashboards that I can edit. I am also unable to find a difference between the ones I can edit and one I can't.

Is there anything on a dashboard that prevents it from being edited?

Comment: does this help? https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005161&language=en_US

Comment: I had a look at this. I am a System Admin so I do have the View All Data permission and Manage Dashboard permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We realized that the dashboard was created in Lightning UI and such dashboards are not editable in Classic UI. Additionally, a dashboard created in Lightning doesn't allow us to change the running user.